# Vertical index Perl

Tags: perl, sum, range

File 1 has ranges 3-9, 2-6 etc

```
3 9
2 6
12 20
```

File2 has values: column 1 indicates the range and column 2 has values.

```
1   4
2   4
3   5
4   4
5   4
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   4
```

I would like to calculate the sum of values (file2, column2) for ranges in file1). Eg: If range is 3-9, then sum of values will be 5+4+4+1+1+1+4 = 20

What I have tried is:

```
open (FILE1,"file1.txt");
open (FILE2,"file2.txt");

@file1 = <FILE1>;
@file2 = <FILE2>;

foreach (@file1)
    {
        @split_file2 = split("\\s",$_); //splitting the file by space


foreach (@file2)
    {
        @split_file2 = split("\\s",$_);  //splitting the file by space


if (@split_file1[0] == @split_file2[0]) //if column0 of file1 matches with column0 of file2
    {
        $x += @split_file2[1];  //sum the column1 of file2 

       if ( @split_file2[0] == @split_file1[0] ) //until column1 of file1 = column0 of file2.

            {
            last;
            }
    }
}}
```

Comment: That code hurts to look at.

Comment: You should still learn basic Perl before you try to write programs in it.

Comment: Saying you are in a hurry, won't make people answer the question more quickly :-) Formatting your code nicely might.

Comment: Look into using the `sum` function from `List::Util` with array slices, e.g. `sum(@file2[$range1 .. $range2])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $f1 = shift;
my $f2 = shift;
open FH1, "<", $f1 or die "$!\n";
open FH2, "<", $f2 or die "$!\n";

my %data;

while (<FH1>) {
    $data{$1} = $2 if ($_ =~ m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/);
}

while (<FH2>) {
    if ($_ =~ m/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/) {
        my $sum;
        for ($1..$2) {
            $sum += $data{$_} if defined($data{$_});
        }
        print "sum for $1-$2: $sum\n" if defined($sum);
    }
}

close FH1;
close FH2;
```

Call: `script.pl values.txt ranges.txt`

Comment: @dan1111 Thanks for your input, I changed my answer accordingly. However, `exists` doesn't check whether or not a hash value for an existing key is defined. Why is it _generally_ preferred then?

Comment: I suppose that point was nitpicking.  You are right about the difference between the two.  In this case, I considered it a check for the existence of a key, since a key without a defined value clearly can't exist.

Answer (score 3):

- Always use `use strict; use warnings;`.
- `split /\s/` is easier to read. `split  ' '` is what you actually want.
- Don't use global variables (e.g. for file handles).
- It's useful to check if `open` succeeds, if only by adding `or die $!`.
- Use meaningful names, not `file1` and `file2`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use List::Util qw( sum );

my $file1 = 'file1.txt';
my $file2 = 'file2.txt';

my @file2;
{    
   open(my $fh, '<', $file2)
      or die "Can't open $file2: $!\n";
   while (<$fh>) {
      my ($k, $v) = split;
      $file2[$k] = $v;
   }
}

{    
   open(my $fh, '<', $file1)
      or die "Can't open $file1: $!\n";
   while (<$fh>) {
      my ($start, $end) = split;
      say sum grep defined, @file2[$start .. $end];
   }
}
```

Comment: `split / /` is rarely what *anyone* wants. Most likely `split ' '` or just `split`

Comment: `say sum @file2[$start .. $end];` is sufficient if each element of the range is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @Borodin, Yeah, that was a typo I was fixing when you were writing your comment.

Comment: Removing undefined values may hide input errors, such as with the range 12 .. 20 and the given data.

Comment: @TLP, I don't think that is an error, but I did give him both options